# How to provide password for Web Deploy on Visual Studio (Mac)

Tags: macos, visual-studio, asp.net-core, webdeploy

Environment

```
MacOS 10.14.6 Mojave, Visual Studio For Mac v8.7.9
API service built on .NET Core framework
```

Issue: I have a .NET Core project that has a web deploy publish profile to deploy updates to the windows server running on EC2 (IIS).
When I was working on windows, I could easily deploy it through the web deploy UI in the visual studio but after I migrated to the macOS, cannot find such option in the visual studio. I can click on the existing web deploy publish option but it always fails because I need to provide the password somewhere. I tried to add `<Password>` under the `pubxml` file but it doesn't read as a valid tag.

Existing publish profiles
[image]

Error

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.403/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish/targets/PublishTargets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(140,5): error : Web deployment task failed. (Connected to the remote computer using the Web Management Service, but could not authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct user name and password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that the credentials represent a user who has permissions to access the site.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.)
    /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.403/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish/targets/PublishTargets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(140,5): error : Make sure the site name, user name, and password are correct. If the issue is not resolved, please contact your local or server administrator.
    /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.403/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish/targets/PublishTargets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(140,5): error : Error details:
    /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.403/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish/targets/PublishTargets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(140,5): error : Connected to the remote computer ("ec2-3-92-105-216.compute-1.amazonaws.com") using the Web Management Service, but could not authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct user name and password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that the credentials represent a user who has permissions to access the site.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.
    /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.403/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish/targets/PublishTargets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(140,5): error : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
    Publish failed to deploy.
```

Comment: Have you found any answer on that topic?..

Comment: @Fellow7000 Unfortunately not ...

Comment: There is a way how to provide the password in the command line of the dotnet but it's not really helpful on Mac as the next thing the dotnet tries is to call another ".exe" file :-/ dotnet publish *projectName*.csproj /p:PublishProfile=*profileName* /p:Password=*yourPsw*

Comment: I see, thanks for your help. I switched back to windows :/

Comment: Looks like I have to do the same. Probably there is a way to publish into the folder and after that manually make a webdeploy v. FTP for example... but, yes, Visual Studio for Mac is way behind the one for Win... pity.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I have not yet found the answer for that but I've found a kind of work around.

I publish the project to a folder (be careful with dotnet parameters) and after that manually copy files in "bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish" v. ftp to my server.

In order to save a lot of time, it makes sense to copy only newer / different size files.

Not elegant at all, but this is the way how it works for me now.

Will be happy to hear, someone found a solution how to store the password for webdeploy on MacOS